# При вызове PHP скрипта, русский текст отображается кракозябрами? Из-за чего это происходит?

Tags: php, echo

Почему ври выводе русского текста через `echo();` в скрипте `PHP`, появляются кракозябры. Кодировка файла `php` уже все перепробывал, все равно везде кракозябры.

Результат смотрю через командную строку. Программа абсолютно банальна.

```
<?php
   echo "Hello world. Слышал, вы учитесь на PHP-программиста!\n";
   echo "Почему бы вам не набрать свое имя для меня:\n";
      $name = trim(fgets(STDIN));
   echo "\nСпасибо, " . $name . ", очень рад с вами познакомиться.\n\n";
?>
```

Comment: В командной строке скорее всего используется UTF-16LE. Пример, как можно переключится на UTF-8 - здесь: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650369/php-utf-8-to-windows-command-line-encoding

Answer (score 1):

Создай файл `.htaccess` в середину напиши: `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`

и поставь файл `.htaccess` в корень сайта.

В вверху `Html` страницы напиши: `<meta charset='UTF-8'>`

проверь функцию: `fgets();` выдает ошибку.

Comment: Дополни ответ дело не только в кодировке по умолчанию